# Ansible: Add user in sshd_config

Tags: sshd, ansible

A new employee has joined and I need to allow him to access test servers. Normally I use template and upload this template on servers depending on the type of environment. But this time I want to use different approach: I only want to add this new user in `sshd_config` at the end of `AllowUsers` if, and only if, the user is not available.

Tried `lineinfile` module but so far no success.

Comment: Sounds good and implementing this is very easy

Comment: Alternately, does your sshd version support the `Include` statement? If so, check my answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 5):

Use the filter [*community.general.jc*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/jc_filter.html#community-general-jc-filter-convert-output-of-many-shell-commands-and-file-types-to-json) to parse */etc/ssh/sshd_config*

Declare the variable

```yaml
  sshd_conf: "{{ sshd_out.stdout|community.general.jc('sshd_conf') }}"
```

and read the file

```yaml
    - command: cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      register: sshd_out
```

Get the list of the configured *AllowUsers*

```yaml
  sshd_allow_users: "{{ sshd_conf.allowusers|d('')|split }}"
```

---

You can use also other modules to read the file (slurp, fetch, ...). To use the filter, you'll have to install [*jc*](https://pypi.org/project/jc/) on the controller. Parse the config on your own if you can't or don't want to install it. Use the command

```yaml
    - command: sshd -T
      register: sshd_out
```

and declare the variable

```yaml
  sshd_allow_users: "{{ sshd_out.stdout_lines|
                        select('match', 'allowusers')|
                        map('split')|map('last') }}"
```

---

Declare the list of the users you want to add and concatenate the lists

```yaml
  sshd_allow_users_add: [alice, bob]
  sshd_conf_update:
    AllowUsers: "{{ (sshd_allow_users + sshd_allow_users_add)|flatten|unique|sort }}"
```

For example, given the file

```bash
shell> grep AllowUsers /etc/ssh/sshd_config
AllowUsers cloe
```

Update it

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        firstmatch: true
        regexp: '^\s*{{ item.key }}\s+(.*)$'
        line: "{{ item.key }} {{ item.value|join(' ') }}"
        validate: sshd -t -f %s
      loop: "{{ sshd_conf_update|dict2items }}"
```

gives in *--chech --diff* mode

```yaml
TASK [lineinfile] ********************************************************************
--- before: /etc/ssh/sshd_config (content)
+++ after: /etc/ssh/sshd_config (content)
@@ -127,4 +127,4 @@
 #  AllowTcpForwarding no
 #  PermitTTY no
 #  ForceCommand cvs server
-AllowUsers cloe
+AllowUsers alice bob cloe

changed: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'AllowUsers', 'value': ['alice', 'bob', 'cloe']})
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all
  become: true

  vars:

    sshd_allow_users_add: [alice, bob]
    sshd_conf_update:
      AllowUsers: "{{ (sshd_allow_users + sshd_allow_users_add)|flatten|unique|sort }}"

    sshd_conf: "{{ sshd_out.stdout|community.general.jc('sshd_conf') }}"
    sshd_allow_users: "{{ sshd_conf.allowusers|d('')|split }}"

  tasks:

    - command: cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      register: sshd_out
      check_mode: false
      changed_when: false

    - debug:
        msg: |
          sshd_conf:
           {{ sshd_conf|to_yaml|indent(2) }}
          sshd_allow_users_add: {{ sshd_allow_users_add }}
          sshd_conf_update:
            {{ sshd_conf_update|to_yaml|indent(2) }}
      when: debug|d(false)|bool
 
    - lineinfile:
        path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        firstmatch: true
        regexp: '^\s*{{ item.key }}\s+(.*)$'
        line: "{{ item.key }} {{ item.value|join(' ') }}"
        validate: sshd -t -f %s
      loop: "{{ sshd_conf_update|dict2items }}"
```

---

Q: ***no filter named ''split''***

A: The filter [*split*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#manipulating-strings) is available since 2.11. If this filter is not available use the method *split()* in the first case

```yaml
  sshd_allow_users: "{{ (sshd_conf.allowusers|d('')).split() }}"
```

and use the filter *regex_replace* in the second case

```yaml
  sshd_allow_users: "{{ sshd_out.stdout_lines|
                        select('match', 'allowusers')|
                        map('regex_replace', '^(.*) (.*)$', '\\2') }}"
```

Comment: Hello Vladimir, Thanks for Help but i receive this error


fatal: []: FAILED! =>
  msg: 'An unhandled exception occurred while templating ''{u''AllowUsers'': u''{{ (sshd_allow_users + sshd_allow_users_add)|flatten|unique|sort }}''}''. Error was a <class ''ansible.errors.AnsibleError''>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while templating ''{{ sshd_conf.allowusers|d('''')|split }}''. Error was a <class ''ansible.errors.AnsibleError''>, original message: template error while templating string: no filter named ''split''. String: {{ sshd_conf.allowusers|d('''')|split }}'

Comment: I added the workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

Frankly, this feels like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) -- you're asking how to implement a specific solution to your problem, but the solution is... suboptimal, at best.

Let's unpack a bit. You want to be able to ensure that new employees that should be authorized to connect to the test servers are permitted to do so via SSH, and you're trying to do that by maintaining a list of `AllowUsers` in the `sshd_config` file. Doing so you're running into the issue that modifying a random config file via ansible can be tricky and `lineinfile` can be hit-or-miss.

Depending on how wedded you are to this particular method, I see a few possible options.

One, like Sotto Voce pointed out already, rather than explicitly specifying the users in the `sshd_config` file you create a system-level group `ssh_allowed` that you add said users to via ansible with the `ansible.builtin.user` module the usual way, and make sure that `sshd_config` has an `AllowGroup ssh_allowed` entry matching the group.

Two, modern-ish versions of sshd support the `Include` statement. If yours does - you may need to check manually - then there would be a simpler solution:

First, add the line

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
```

To the main `sshd_config` config file, then create a file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/01-authusers.conf` which you can generate via the template builtin because it's entirely independent of the rest of the server-level sshd config.

Answer (score 1):

(This was originally a comment, but I've moved it to an answer)

When I did something similar, I used a static list of groups in an `AllowGroups` line of the `sshd_config` file, and managed access through ordinary Unix/Linux group membership. The facilities in Ansible (or other config management suites) for managing group membership are much easier to use than editing the middle of an sshd_config file, and if you follow the common practice of creating users with a primary group that matches the username, `AllowGroups` can allow individual users as well as groups.

Note that `AllowGroups`/`AllowUsers` work in a way that's unexpected to most people.  If any group/user exists on the `AllowGroups`/`AllowUsers` line, then **only the groups/users on the line are allowed** to log in via SSH.  **All other groups/users are denied.**  IMO the names `AllowOnlyTheseGroups` and `AllowOnlyTheseUsers` would more accurately describe how they work.

Be careful about trying to configure multiple `AllowGroups` or `AllowUsers` lines in your `sshd_config` file.  These two parameters are like most other SSH config parameters: the first one that appears in the config file wins.  The second, third, etc., appearances are ignored.  Even if they appear in extension files called out by `Include`.